# How to launch minecraft 1.7.2 from Terminal / Command Line

Tags: command-line, java, minecraft

I've been playing with the new Yggdrasil authserver that mojang created and I have been learning how to get authentication keys etc. Now I want to know how I can launch minecraft from terminal (UBUNTU) (1.7.2). I've looked everywhere on stackoverflow and google and can only find stuff for the old methods.

The old code such as:

```
java -cp ".minecraft/bin/*" -Djava.library.path=".minecraft/bin/natives/" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "username" "login id"
```

no longer works with the updates around 1.7.2
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method I used that works (only tested on Windows XP):

> @echo off
>   
> cd\
>   
> set MCDIR=%APPDATA%\.minecraft
>   
> cd %MCDIR%
>   
> java -Xmx512M -Djava.library.path="%MCDIR%\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2-natives" -cp "%MCDIR%\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.3\authlib-1.3.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%MCDIR%\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%MCDIR%\versions\1.7.2\1.7.2.jar" net.minecraft.client.main.Main  --username **[player name]** --version 1.7.2 --gameDir C:\DOCUME~1\**[USER]**\APPLIC~1\MINECR~1 --assetsDir C:\DOCUME~1\**[USER]**\APPLIC~1\MINECR~1\assets --accessToken **[obtain from launcher_profiles.json in MC directory]** --uuid (Default)

Before this will work, you MUST run Minecraft and open the folder "versions\1.7.2\1.7.2-natives-xxxx", where xxxx is a random number and copy the contents to a new folder called "1.7.2-natives" or without the numbers.

Note: Change [USER] to your user account in Windows.  If your user account is >8 characters, you have to stop at 6 characters and put the "~1" on the end (MS-DOS format).  [player name] can just be like Player or any name you wish.  The launcher_profiles.json file (in main MC folder) is where you obtain the access token that you put in here.

Save using notepad as minecraft.bat

You can create a VBS file so this batch runs without a command prompt window (looks nicer).  To do this, create a VBS file (minecraft.vbs) using notepad, edit and add this code:

> Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
>   
> Dim strArgs
>   
> strArgs = "cmd /c minecraft.bat"
>   
> oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false

Create a shortcut using (minecraft.vbs) and you are all set!

Comment: `[player name] can just be like Player or any name you wish.` - Will that be the name that other players see in multiplayer or will it only be client-side?

Comment: Does it have to be so long? Aren't there any other options?